# Is it possible to self-reference a column using transform

Tags: r

Is there a function to self-reference a column in transform, once it's already been identified without retyping it?

For example, let's say you have a snippet of the following code:

```
returns = readxl::read_excel(returns_filepath) %>%
    transform(Asset_Class = as.character(Asset_Class)) %>%
    transform(Standardized_Date = as.Date(Standardized_Date)) %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

In the first transform call, is there a function that could be placed within the as.character call that would transform the already specified Asset_Class column without specifying it a second time? Something that would look something like this: transform(Asset_Class = as.character(self()))

Comment: Use `dplyr`, specifically, `mutate`/`across`: `mutate(across(Asset_Class, as.character))`

Comment: Helpful. Works as needed. But just of curiosity, you are not aware of any function that self references a given column. Something like everything(), just on one column that's already been selected?

Answer (score 0):

Thats for what `within` is useful. The usage is slightly different, there are curly brackets, new lines, and no commas. Assignment usually with `<-`, but `=` also works.

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(15), 5, 3))


d <- within(d, {
  X1.yz <- X1/sum(d)    ## creates `X1.yz`
  X1.yz.sq <- X1.yz^2   ## references X1.yz` 
})
head(d)
#            X1          X2           X3     X1.yz.sq       X1.yz
# 1 -0.02944488  0.69686258 -0.273645701 5.952493e-05  0.00771524
# 2 -0.41386885 -1.05636841 -0.467845325 1.175993e-02  0.10844322
# 3  1.11338602 -0.04069848 -1.238252328 8.510809e-02 -0.29173291
# 4 -0.48099284 -1.55154482 -0.007762034 1.588388e-02  0.12603126
# 5 -0.43316903  1.16716955 -0.800282178 1.288232e-02  0.11350031
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `cur_data()` and `cur_column()` attributes from within a `mutate` or `summarise` context.

`cur_data()` refers to the data frame, `cur_column()` is the string value of the selected column.  Combine them to capture the selected column.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(value = rnorm(10))

df %>%
  mutate(across(value, list(
    foo = ~cur_data()[cur_column()] * 10, 
    bar = ~paste0(cur_column(), "_", letters[1:10]))
  ))
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 10 x 3
     value value_foo value_bar
     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>    
 1  0.827      8.27  value_a  
 2  0.694      6.94  value_b  
 3 -0.536     -5.36  value_c  
 4  0.847      8.47  value_d  
 5  0.0894     0.894 value_e  
 6 -0.639     -6.39  value_f  
 7 -0.561     -5.61  value_g  
 8 -0.508     -5.08  value_h  
 9  1.25      12.5   value_i  
10 -1.04     -10.4   value_j
```